# Strange CMD errors only when CMD is opened from my program

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, shadow-copy

This is a weird one for sure.

If I open a command prompt window directly (searching cmd in start, right click > open command window here, cmd within bat file, etc....) all commands entered run perfectly fine.

If I open a command prompt window from within my C++ application (`system("cmd");` or `QProcess::startDetached("cmd");` etc....) the commands I enter throw errors.

Here are a few commands that don't work in the cmd opened from my app:

```
vssadmin delete shadows /all
vssadmin list shadows
wmic
shadowcopy
```

and so on... I get `Class not registered` and `Initialization failure` errors all around. Anything to do with shadow copies isn't working at all. But again, the weird thing is, those same commands work perfectly fine when cmd was opened traditionally (not from a program). Both instances of cmd have admin privileges.

So my question is, how come the way I open cmd affects whether or not some commands work? Everything I can see says there should be no difference.

Comment: Your launching cmd from a vanilla windows exe?

Comment: When opened like every other human being, all commands work fine. When opened within my uber basic generic Qt C++ project, those listed commands (and more to do with shadow copies) don't work. So yes. vanilla as it gets. This has been tested with multiple programs on multiple computers. Try it yourself, I bet it will do the same thing.

Comment: Is the output of the `set` command the same for both?

Comment: No they're different. The one from within my program has about 3 times more stuff.

Comment: Also, entering the command directly like `system("vssadmin delete shadows /all");` just skips right to the error.

Comment: Run c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe and you'll probably get the exact same errors.  Time to start building programs to target x64.

Comment: Yep. Calling `system("c:\\windows\\syswow64\\cmd.exe");` and entering the commands returns the errors. Same for when I open it directly. Calling `system("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe");` also returns the errors. But works fine when opened directly.

Comment: Other than compiling as 64 bit, know of any quick hotfixes to send the commands to the 64 bit version of cmd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

32-bit applications running on WOW64 will be put under [file system redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector). Therefore if your app is a 32-bit one, the call `system("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe");` will be redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` and 32-bit cmd will always be invoked. You have some solutions:

- Use `system("c:\\windows\\sysnative\\cmd.exe");` to access the real system32 folder and get the 64-bit cmd
- Turn off file system redirection explicitly (should be avoided in general)
- Or better compiling it as a 64-bit app.

Comment: Thanks! Not only did this work, but I've learned a lot of new stuff in the process. :)

Comment: You should avoid the second option ("turn off file system redirection") as it isn't thread-safe.

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes I just listed it as a "possible" way here but it's not recommended as MS said ["A 64-bit executable file located under %windir%\System32 cannot be launched from a 32-bit process, because the file system redirector redirects the path to %windir%\SysWOW64. Do not disable redirection to accomplish this; use %windir%\Sysnative instead."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)